# 1 column 2 data type issue + field not defined issues

Tags: google-bigquery

I have struggled with this problem for 1 day And finally asking here.

My startup where I am working is logging user data to BigQuery by google cloud logging.

At some point we add 1 column (field) and then we change the data type of this column(field). And It's impossible to query this field through the wholetime of this Table.

The images below is showing the field that I mentioned above. And shows the timeline of the field ("jsonPayload.page.result_count.total") created in 2022/09/09 and the data type changed from STRING to FLOAT.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And If I try to query like below. the error comes out.

[image]

How can I query this field "jsonPayload.page.result_count.total" without any problems?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a BigQuery [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations) using wildcard wherein

> If a single scanned table has a schema mismatch (that is, a column with the same name is of a different type), the query fails with the error **Cannot read field of type X as Y Field: column_name**.

Possible workaround for this is to identify your tables that have the same **Data Type** for `jsonPayload.page.result_count.total` and then alter your wildcard query so that only ALL tables with **STRING** data type for `jsonPayload.page.result_count.total` will be queried.

You can query using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to help you identify what tables have STRING and FLOAT64 just like my example below.

```sql
select table_name, column_name, data_type
from `your-project.your-dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
where table_name LIKE '%table%'
order by table_name
```

**My result:**

[image]

On my example, `jsonPayload.page.result_count.total` in `table1` and `table11` are STRING and can be in a single query and `table2` and `table21` will be in a separate query.

Once identified, I can now create my wildcard query based on my checking of data types above, and then use **UNION ALL** to join the results (results of STRING and FLOAT64) in a single query and then cast the FLOAT64 into STRING as shown below.

```sql
select jsonPayload.page.result_count.total from `your-table.your-dataset.yourwildcard*`
union all select cast(jsonPayload.page.result_count.total as string) from `your-table.your-dataset.yourwildcard2*`
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail and great reply! Will try the approach that you wrote! 

Thanks you so so much!! :D